# Rxjs map operator used after switchMap operator in a pipe can't find lift() function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5

Scenario -  The page needs to load data asynchronous from an external source and show the loading image based upon the isLoading property. 
Using an EventEmitter to manually trigger data refresh with a button, but in demo just subscribing to retrieve data (for simplicity). 
Pipe is used to retrieve data and to set isLoading to false or true.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  tableRefreshEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>(true);
  isLoading = false;
  data: Observable<{}>;

  constructor() {
    this.data = merge(this.tableRefreshEmitter)
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      tap(() => {
        this.isLoading = true;
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        // retrieve observable from http service example
        return observableOf({});
      },
      map(data => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        return data;
      })      
    ));

    this.data.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
  }
}
```

Code produces a error:
[image]

Currently stuck on finding the culprit and any help would be appreciated on how to resolve the error.

Working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-lift-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in parenthesis. You have:

```
switchMap(() => {
    // retrieve observable from http service example
    return observableOf({});
},
map(data => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return data;
})
```

But this way you're passing `map` as second parameter to `switchMap`.

You probably want to have this instead:

```
switchMap(() => {
    // retrieve observable from http service example
    return observableOf({});
}),
map(data => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return data;
})
```

Your updated demo prints "loaded": https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-lift-missing-ypue7b?file=app/app.component.ts

Btw you can use `tap` instead of `map` if you just want to perform some side effects and don't want to modify the data:

```
tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Can't evade always these small mistakes, but i appreciate the help and the suggestion.